# how to echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] within a string

Tags: php, echo

I can't figure out the syntax for quotes within quotes within quotes.? (edit: was not a matter of this, had an echo where it should be concatenated. See my answer below for corrected code)

This code brings a syntax error

```
$stringData="<?echo'<form method=\"post\" action=\"<? echo$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>\"><button type=\"submit\">';?>";
```

I've tried many combinations of quotes and backslashes.

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bad grammar. This should work ;)

If you want to echo it:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"><button type="submit">';
```

If you want to keep it on a variable:

```
$string = '<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"><button type="submit">';
```

Comment: @KevinGulling did u try this?

Comment: replace your line with mine. We are just linking strings together and echoing. Yours was simply bad built. It is the same ;)

Comment: I posted a new solution in case you just want it on a variable

Comment: I need the echo in the variable like I posted in the question...

Comment: That is not possible in this programming language. I suggest you to ask what you really need and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had an echo where it shouldn't be. Sorry for wasting your time.

```
$stringData="<?echo'<form method=\"post\" action=\" .'\$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']'.\"><button type=\"submit\">';?>";
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Riad information as to how to solve a question is relevant in a answer, even if this question should altogether be deleted since it is only a typographical error.